# Proving associativity on $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'd like to check this proof I made:

Prove the associative law holds on $\mathbb{Q}$.  Let $r,s,t$ be elements of $\mathbb{Q}$.  Prove $(rs)t=r(st)$.

Proof starts here:

Let $r,s,t$ be elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ where $r,s,t$ are not equal to zero.  Suppose we have $(rs)t$.  This is equal to:

$(rs)t=(sr)t$

$=s(rt)$

$=s(tr)$

$=(st)r$

$=r(st)$

$=r(st)$

Thus, we can see that the law of associativity holds on $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: How do you justify $(sr)t=s(rt)$ from the first to the second line?

Comment: You beg the question in the second line of your proof, where you assert $(sr)t = s(rt)$. To prove this, you're going to have to use the definition of multiplication on $\mathbb{Q}$ from its construction from integers.

Comment: You use associativity twice in your proof of associativity :D

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?

Comment: You'll have to look in your textbook for where they define the rationals, as well as the sum/product of two rationals, and use that definition to prove associativity

Comment: It follows by associativity of integers with respect to multiplication. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any rational number $q \in \mathbb{Q} \backslash \{0\}$ can be written as $\frac{x}{y}$ for some $x,y \in \mathbb{Z} \backslash \{0\}$. Thus, we can write $r,s,t \in \mathbb{Q} \backslash \{0\}$ as $\frac{a}{b}$, $\frac{c}{d}$, and $\frac{e}{f}$, respectively, for $a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb{Z} \backslash \{0\}$. And so it follows that we have
$$\begin{align} (rs)t &= \left(\frac{ac}{bd}\right)\frac{e}{f} \\&= \frac{ace}{bdf} \\&= \frac{a}{b}\left(\frac{ce}{df}\right) \\&= r(st) \,\,,\end{align}$$
where each of the above equalities were by the definition of multiplication of nonzero rational numbers and by the associativity of multiplication in the integers. This proves associativity of multiplication in the rationals.

Comment: I am SOOO bad at proofs!  Thanks for this.  Do you have any recommendations for someone starting out on Real analysis for study aids?  The text I have is "The Real Numbers and Real Analysis".  I'm not too fond of it.  Thanks again!

Comment: I recommend "Calculus" by Michael Spivak...that was my first higher mathematics textbook